# What is wrong with this post, to cause such a massive down vote barrage?

Tags: discussion

[Sources for Christian themes and motifs in Naruto?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24028/sources-for-christian-themes-and-motifs-in-naruto)

Looking through the question, it seems like a decent question to me. Asking if there are any sources stating the potential influence of Christianity in Naruto *all tough asking discussion groups potentially is on the edge* I don't see why this question should receive such a amount of down votes.

Could some of the people that decided to Down vote this particular question elaborate as to why they find this particular question to be bad? Just like [@Senshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1908/senshin) states in his comment

> This question is the most down voted **(non-deleted)** post on the site by a large margin, and I don't see why.

Comment: Incidentally, the only deleted post with a score of -11 (this post was at -10 when I commented) is the "Help me identify this baby prenis!" one that I'm not even going to link to because it was so terrible.

Comment: I honestly don't know either. I didn't upvote it, but I certainly don't see why it's worth of a downvote, let alone 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it's at first glance a  seemingly ridiculous question.

At first glance, you think that the user is drawing parallels just to fit their own views. This wasn't helped by the title "*Naruto the Christian?*" that it had before.

After the edit though, this question has improved a lot and doesn't really deserve the downvotes anymore - but I imagine there was a bit of "this has a big downvote amount so it must be bad" attitude with some users.

Whilst the question doesn't interest me at all, I do recognize that it's a legitimate question.

Comment: Makes allot of sense. Well hope the down voters notice the post, and re-evaluate their original judgment.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't downvote it, but the others who did probably did so because there was a wall of text and then a question.

Probably should have put the question up top.

Comment: Down voting purely because of that is just plain **wrong**. If seen bigger walls of text, which even managed to receive allot of up votes. All tough I do agree, there could be some TL;DR for the lazy readers.

Comment: Those walls of text are usually answers. IMO good questions are short, concise, and to the point. There should only be enough detail for context. The whole point of asking a question is usually to get an answer. Why would you self sabotage by asking it in a way that most people don't want to bother with? With that said, downvotting means the question could be improved. I'm guessing the improvement is to make it clear what's being asked for in an answer.

Comment: It wasn't a wall of text to begin with. It had garnered at least 4 downvotes before it was [edited into a longer question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/24028/revisions).

Comment: @Killua interesting, i still think having the question up top would have removed a few of those downvotes